# How to pass a Stream using soap UI

Tags: c#, wcf, testing, soapui

I am having trouble testing a WCF service method with soap UI which accepts a Stream object. This is the Object the service method has as input parameter:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = Constants.NAMESPACE)]
public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 2)]
    public long Length { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 3)]
    public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (FileByteStream != null)
        {
            FileByteStream.Close();
            FileByteStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The generated request in soap UI:

```
...
<ws:File>
  <ws:FileName>?</ws:FileName>
  <ws:Length>?</ws:Length>
  <ws:FileByteStream>
    <sys:__identity>?</sys:__identity>
  </ws:FileByteStream>
</ws:File>
```

What do I need to do in soap UI to test this method?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to call your request with specific TestRequest Properties.

Turn the TestRequest Properties :
`Inline Response Attachments` = True
`Enable Inline Files` = True

Also if your request send the file you need to attach the files in your request.

In your request click on the `tab attachments` and add the file.